# Application does not displays, but works

Tags: qt, qt5, qt-quick

I'm new in Qt and I'm trying to write simple app with qtquick as described [here](https://qmlbook.github.io/en/ch01/index.html#qt-5-introduction).
My code :

```
import QtQuick 2.3

Image {
    id: root
    source: "images/background.png"
}
```

When I build it and type "Run" button, it seems works, but I can't see any window at all!

What am I doing wrong?

`Qt 5.3`; `qtquick 2.3`

System is `Debian 8 Jessie`

**UPD:**
main.cpp is primitive:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{ 
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Can you show a `main.cpp`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation:

> Unlike QQuickView, QQmlApplicationEngine does not automatically create
>   a root window. If you are using visual items from Qt Quick, you will
>   need to place them inside of a Window.

So you need to add [`Window`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-window-window.html) around your `Image`.